Does Python allow defining a C function that a shared library can call directly?
I figured out how to let Python call a function from my shared library:
import ctypes

def bar():
    return 1337

dll = ctypes.PyDLL("./mod.so")

assert dll.foo(ctypes.c_float(42)) == 42 + 1337

where mod.so can call that bar Python function like so in C:
int foo(float f) {
    PyObject *module = PyImport_ImportModule("main");
    PyObject *bar = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "bar");
    PyObject *args = PyTuple_Pack(0);
    PyObject *result = PyObject_CallObject(bar, args);
    return f + PyLong_AsInt(result);
}

I'm essentially looking for a way to let the C foo() function call a function in the Python code directly, without needing anything Python specific like PyObject_CallObject(). This is what I'm trying to turn the C file into:
int foo(float f) {
    return f + bar();
}

Context
My programming language (see my blog post) its compiler+linker outputs a generic mod.so that is supposed to be usable by any programming language, so not just Python.
This mod.so works out-of-the-box for C and C++, because the shared library simply uses a call instruction to call the main executable's bar function. Python (and most other high-level languages) on the other hand don't allow you to call a Python function like this directly. This makes sense, as Python wraps primitive C types in custom structs. This is why we needed the PyObject_CallObject() call in the above code.
I could write a program that replaces all of the call instructions with the chain of PyImport_ImportModule() + PyObject_GetAttrString() + etc. calls, but I'd prefer leaving the mod.so alone for technical reasons.
What I got working is putting an adapter.c as a middleman between the Python code and the mod.so. adapter.so just exists to expose a bar wrapper function that mod.so can call directly, containing the PyObject_CallObject and co. calls. See my previous Stack Overflow question for the rough code.
Because my programming language already requires the game developer to document the mod API in mod_api.json, it is possible to regenerate this adapter.c file automatically, but ideally this step wouldn't be required at all.
Looping back to the post's title
Does Python allow defining a C function that a shared library can call directly? If so, then I wouldn't have to worry about modifying mod.so nor having an adapter.c. Thanks.

ctypes allows to create callback functions (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions). So you could provide a pointer to this callback function to foo and it can then call the function.

@MichaelButscher Thanks, I didn't know that. I unfortunately don't think it'll help me in this situation though, since I'm looking for a way to have the call to bar in mod.so stay a single machine code instruction, without modifying mod.so to specifically cater to Python. I'll update the post to be clearer.

No, you have to use the Python C API to call Python from C, just as you have shown.  You can pass a Python function to C as mentioned in the first comment and use it as a callback, but that still uses ctypes to wrap the Python call in similar code to convert C parameters to Python parameters, make the call, then convert the Python result back to a C result.  There is an example in ctypes - Callback Functions.

I had typed this in and then scrolled up to see that you probably answered your own question already.  I was able to retrieve this information from the Python docs at docs.python.org for 'ctypes', a foreign function library for Python.
It basically allows you to call functions either in dlls or shared libraries.  Source code is located at Lib/ctypes at docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.
